# Changing object type of the whole column imported from csv in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, pandas, numpy

So I am trying to analyze some data imported from csv file and i have copied some columns from the original file (loan.csv). Most of them had entries of float64 type but two of them (loan_status and emp_length) had entries of object type. I did some preprocessing in order to change characters into numbers and now they are of int64 type. However I would like them to be float64 as well. When I try to change it for example by inserting

```
 loan_stat=loan_stat.astype(np.float64)
```

in line 12 i get the error that '"DataFrame" object is not callable'. I would also like to change the type of emp_length which I had to map as you can probably see but it is now of int64 type as well and i get the same error when i try to change them into float.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

data_file = pd.read_csv('loan.csv')

# variable preprocessing

data_file['loan_status'] = np.where(data_file['loan_status'].isin(['Fully 
Paid', 'Current']), 1, 0)
loan_stat=data_file['loan_status']

m = {
   'n/a': 0,     
   '< 1 year': 0,
   '1 year': 1,
   '2 years': 2,
   '3 years': 3,
   '4 years': 4,
   '5 years': 5,
   '6 years': 6,
   '7 years': 7,
   '8 years': 8,
   '9 years': 9,
   '10+ years': 10
}
emp_length=data_file.emp_length.map(m)

annual_inc=data_file['annual_inc']
delinq_2yrs=data_file['delinq_2yrs']
dti=data_file['dti']
loan_amnt=data_file['loan_amnt']
installment=data_file['installment']
int_rate=data_file['int_rate']
total_acc=data_file['total_acc']
open_acc=data_file['open_acc']
pub_rec=data_file['pub_rec']
acc_now_delinq=data_file['acc_now_delinq']

#variables combined into one dataset

data_set=[annual_inc, delinq_2yrs, dti, emp_length, loan_amnt, installment, 
int_rate, open_acc, total_acc, acc_now_delinq, loan_stat]

result=pd.concat(data_set,axis=1)
```

Thanks for some suggestions

Comment: can you add an example from loan.csv?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/wendykan/lending-club-loan-data/downloads/lending-club-loan-data.zip

Comment: I can do the conversion to numpy float without any issues.

Comment: could you paste the exact line you add?

Comment: I used the exact same line as you did:  loan_stat=loan_stat.astype(np.float64) . Could you post the error message?

Comment: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Comment: what line of code is producing this error? Is it the line I just posted above?

Comment: the error comes from the line loan_stat=data_file['loan_status'] but without the conversion to float it doesnt return error

Comment: ok. nevermind. It worked. I had to many parenthesis:). Thanks for the help!!

Comment: ok, glad to head that!